# PYTHON print function, no result, no error with print

Tags: python, python-2.7

when I use python with the following codes, there is no output. what is wrong?
I can print("Top terms per cluster:") when I type the code in the IDLE, however, when I use ipython with jupyter notebook, the codes can not work, there is no error and output with the code. thx

```
print ("Top terms per cluster:")
```

Comment: Is this the only code you have? Is it in a file, the IDLE console, python console, piece of paper stuck to the screen, etc?

Comment: it is the only code I have, I just want to print the sentences, but the print can not work. I do not what is wrong , there is not a file

Comment: You aren't running the code properly. That code will in fact print output.

Comment: so what can I do ??? and How to use it?

Comment: Open the IDLE console, or python console, and type the code there. Then press Enter.

Comment: thank you for your answer, when I type the code in IDLE console, it works, however ,I am using ipython with jupyter notebook, it does not work yet.

Comment: You should put that in the question.

Comment: thx, I have edited the question.

Comment: are you pressing shift + enter to execute the cell?

Comment: 'confused by the ui of jupyter notebook' is probably not really a programming question.

Comment: yes,I execute the cell by pressing shift+enter,

Comment: Do you have a firewall running, such as Sophos?

Comment: I do not think so, I just run it normally, How  can I  have a firewall running??and why need it ?

Comment: A quick search of google suggested that some firewall software on your pc might block the results from returning. I am not familiar with jupyter, but it seems to be using the internet to store your information. I may be wrong, but it seems a better option than "no idea". Try disabling your PC firewall and see if you get results that way.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this works for you if you are using python 2.7:

```
print 'Hello world'
```